# HTML images not displaying

Tags: html, css, image, icons

I have this code in the body of my HTML-based page:
`<img style="float: right; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;" scr="tumblr.png" height="30px" width="30px">`

Ideally, it should display a Tumblr icon in the upper-right corner. However, when I view it in a browser, I just see a white box with a gray outline. For whatever reason, the image won't display. (I know it isn't a naming issue, because a different page on my site uses the same image, and it's displaying fine.

Here's some of the CSS if that helps:

```
  #header {
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    background-color:FFF;
    color: #000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    width:70%;
    left:12%;
    height:17%;
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-right:3%;
    padding-top:2%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
  }

  #header_right {
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
  }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't working on this anymore. But if you are, you have a typo in your  tag.

You have: `scr="tumblr.png"`
It should be: `src="tumblr.png"`

If that's still not working, you need to make sure you have your paths correct. If tumblr.png is in the same directory as your html file, it will work.

But if you have tumblr.png in an images directory, you would need: `src="images/tumblr.png"`